# Problem in downloading ERA5 data

Tags: geophysics

it's my first time to ask question here, thank you for your answer(if any:)

So I need to download the ERA5 land daily data, and as I try to download it from the website, the progress bar always shows 0.0/26.2G. And as I tried to use the API code, the python shows error with   raise Exception(error)

Exception:

401 Authorization Required

## 401 Authorization Required

---

nginx/1.16.1

As I am using the MAC pro and the CONDA system, can anyone tells me how to solve this issue?

Many thanks:)

Comment: Using the API will probably not solve your problem as the data package you want to download is quite large. This means you will not be priority for the system. Less large downloads will be given priority. So if it is possible for you to download the data piecewise, do so. Regarding the authorization error: https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/api-how-to could help.

Comment: Sure thank you I now know it may probably be the network problem, so therefore I would ask for someone else's help. Thank you.

Comment: What details can you provide? If I recall correctly, accessing ERA data requires login information.